# Mac os x systems programmng and bsd

Tags: macos, bsd, system

I'd like to get into some mac os x systems programming and wondered, although mac os x is a Mach and bsd hybrid, would a bsd programming book suffice since I can't seem to find any books on mac os x systems level coding (or mac os x architecture)?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks
ste

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to pick up a copy of Amit Singh's excellent [Mac OS X Internals: A Systems Approach](http://www.osxbook.com/).

Beyond that, books on BSD can be helpful, yes, though it depends on what level of system programming you're interested in.  If you're mainly going to be working with the kernel, it won't be as useful.

Comment: Thanks Stephen,

I had a look at the book, but I'm not sure that it covers the latest Leopard/Snow Leopard intel editions of the OS.

Comment: @SteJav: It's not completely up to date, but the information is still quite good.  Appendix A covers OS X/Intel.

Comment: Thanks Stephen,

I'll make a purchase and have a read.

Cheers
Ste

Answer (score 1):

you might find the [System Technology Overview](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/SystemTechnology/SystemTechnology.html) from the Apple Developer Connection website helpful.
It contains links to several more documents which go into more detail about specific OS X technologies.

You might also find more information if you browse the index of the [Apple Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/navigation/index.html). For example the 'Getting Started' articles or the 'Drivers, Kernel & Hardware' topics.

Comment: Thanks MKroehnert,

the "System Technology Overview" is quite good, but I was hoping for something similar to the "Solaris Internals" or "Windows Internals 5".  The book Stephen Canon recommends "Mac OS X Internals: A Systems Approach" sounds like the type of book I'm after, but looking at the authors website: www.osxbook.com, the forum suggests the book doesn't cover Leopard/Snow Leopard Intel.